# controllerDidChangeContent: called every time I create a ManagedObject in Core Data

Tags: core-data, tableview, reload, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a tableview using NSFetchedResultsController to load data from the Core Data store, I am implementing controllerDidChangeContent: to update the table with new data (loaded from a remote source), however, the delegate method controllerDidChangeContent: is being called as soon as I create a Managed Object, it was my understanding that this should only be called when I message save: on the corresponding Managed Object Context.

Is there a parameter to set to enable this ?

I am downloading an XML with many items to insert into the tableview and I'm getting crashes because I am creating my Managed Objects on the fly and appending information on the fly, some of which are required to be displayed in the Table View Cell.

Therefore by controllerDidChangeContent: being called each time I create a new Managed Object, the properties I require to make the Table View Cell are not yet ready.

Any insight would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't disable this behavior of the NSFetchedResultsController. To prevent this you can create a second NSManagedObjectContext, do all your inserts, changes and deletes there and finally merge both contexts with the `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:`

As your are downloading an XML file you also should do this in a background thread to prevent the UI being blocked for user inputs.

Comment: You can see an example of this over at [Cocoa Is My Girlfriend](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/08/22/importing-and-displaying-large-data-sets-in-core-data/)